# Angular 2 - Number pipe for scientific notation numbers

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I'm using number pipe (number:'1.2-2') to round off the decimals. It works fine for standard format numbers but for scientific format numbers (exponential) the result is returned in standard format.

For example if I apply the above number pipe to 1.336274995924138e+306 I expect 1.34e+306 but what I get is 1336274995924140000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.

The same works fine in Angular JS 1.x.

Please advise how can I get back result in the same notation as the original number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For num = 1.336274995924138e+306

```
num.toPrecision(3)
```

results in scientific notation with 3 significant figures...i.e.
1.34e+306

Here's a Plunker example with a custom pipe that will use **toPrecision** when the number is large, otherwise, it'll use the **DecimalPipe** that you've been using. [Custom Pipe Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/vEFRof5yXinnNZwObOBb?p=preview)

If you want to incorporate this in you codebase, check out how its referenced in the main app module.

Comment: Thanks. toPrecision works fine for scientific format but not for standard format numbers. In my case I need something that can work with both standard and scientific formats.
So if my input is in standard format, the pipe must round it to 2 decimal places and the result must be in standard format. And if the input is in scientific format, then the result must be in scientific format.