# Angular - Limit decimal to two places without rounding off

Tags: angular

I am using the [decimal pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe) to limit decimal number to two places:

```
{{amount | number:'1.2-2'}}
```

But unfortunately the above pipe rounds off the number. Is there any way I can limit the output to two places after decimal without rounding off the number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest that you write a custom pipe to do this.

The documentation is found here:

https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes

Here is a good example how to use a pipe for formating numbers

[Angular 2 - Number pipe for scientific notation numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859972/angular-2-number-pipe-for-scientific-notation-numbers?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Number pipe will round the numbers.
You can use my formula and create a custom pipe.
Example to show 2digit.

```
let number = 1236.25658
let customDigit = parseInt(number * 100) / 100;
console.log(customDigit) //return 1236.25
```